# objective-c - Why can I assign values to pointers?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, object

I understand pointers work with addresses and not the data itself. This is why I need to use the address-of (&) operator below as I need to assign the address of num to the pointer and not the actual value of num (40).

```
int num = 40;
int *numPtr = &num;
```

Therefore i'm confused as to why I can do this.

```
NSString *str = @"hello";
```

I've created a pointer str but instead of giving it an address i'm able to assign it some data, a literal string.

I thought pointers could only hold memory addresses so why am I able to directly assign it some data?

For someone trying to get their head around pointers and objects this is very confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a reason you put an @ before string literals (when you want an NSString and not a C string)  in objective-c

`@"String"` is basically equivalent to `[NSString stringWithCString:"string"]` which returns a pointer to an NSString object containing the value "string"

It is the same way `1` is a c type integer, but `@1` is a NSNumber representing the value of 1. If you see an @ it means "this is shorthand for creating an object". (@[] for NSArrays, @{} for NSDictionarys, @(), @123, @YES, @NO for NSNumbers, and @"" for NSString)

Comment: OK I didn't realise all that was going on in the background. So it seems a pointer is actually being returned rather than the string. I'm a lot clearer on what the @ symbol means now as well. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

No you are not assigning a literal string to it, `@` makes a `NSString` object with the string value `hello`.

In most C languages strings are just an array of `char`, where `char` is a primitive type like `int` like in your example.

Comment: OK I was missing the significance of the @ and what it actually means. Seems there's more going on in the background than I realised. Thanks

Comment: Yes there is, the `@` can also be used to create `NSNumber` objects, like: `NSNumber *number = @42;` or array objects: `NSArray *myArray =@[@42, @"The answer"]'`, etc...

Answer (score 0):

C does not have strings. Usually char arrays are used to represent them.

```
NSString *str = @"hello";
```

can be thought of as short hand (literal) for:

```
char charArray[] = "hello";
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:charArray length:sizeof(charArray) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];   // disregard character encoding for this example
```

or

```
unichar bla[] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
str = [[NSString alloc] initWithCharacters:bla length:sizeof(bla)];
```

So an object is created and thus you need a pointer.